# Android - detect rooted device in C/C++ code

Tags: android, c

There are many samples showing how to detect the rooted android device in java code, I need to do this in C code (wrapped by jni of course), couldn't find any example. Please help. 
Thanks.

Found something after research, in JNI C code: system("echo \"test\" > /data/test.txt\n");

1. returns 512 on rooted devices, 512 means error code 2 (major error).
2. returns 256 on un-rooted devices, 256 means error code 1 (minor error) permission denied.

Should checking return error 512 be enough to say the device is rooted?

Comment: If you know how to do it in Java, why not do it in Java and call it from C via JNI?

Comment: The requirement is do it in C.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something simpler.

Have a flag in Java to determine whether the phone is rooted. if yes, when you will do a JNI call, pass this flag indicating the same. Then you can handle a code flow for rooted/non-rooted in C.

Comment: Thank you Royston, but your way is still do it in Java. I want to do the check in C code.